# Why the action of $D_{2n}$ on $\{a_i\}$ should look like this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions, dihedral-groups

Here is the question I want to understand:

Assume $n$ is an even positive integer and show that $D_{2n}$ acts on the set consisting of pairs of opposite vertices of a regular $n$-gon. Find the kernel of this action (label vertices as usual).

Here is a part of the solution I found online:

" Let us assume that $n$ is even, and label the vertices of the $n$-gon clockwise as: $0,1,2, \dots, n-1.$ Now by using the set of ordered pairs defined by $\{a_i\},$ we can represent the $n/2$ pairs of opposite vertices as: $$\{a_i\} = \Big\{\left( i, \frac{n}{2} + i\right) : 0 \leq i \leq \frac{n}{2} \Big\}$$

Now on the elements $\{a_i\}$ define the action of $D_{2n},$ so that the elements of $D_{2n}$ permute the set as follows:

$r^k a_i = a_{{i-k}\mod n}$ and $s^k a_i = a_{{i-kn/2}\mod n}$ "

But I do not understand why the actions of $r^k$ and $s^k$ on $a_i$ looks like this. Could anyone clarify this to me please?

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text; instead, type them up. Also, where did these pictures come from exactly?

Comment: @Shaun ok I am so sorry, I will edit my post.

Comment: @Shaun Oh I think you edited it?

Comment: Thank you, @Brain.

Comment: Yes, but I left a few things that need doing.

Comment: @Shaun ok, I am editing it now.

Comment: You still have editing to do. You haven't mentioned where you're getting these quotes from either.

Comment: @Shaun I completed my edit now. I do not understand your second statement. Are you asking about the source of the solution?

Comment: That's better. Thank you. However, you still haven't specified the website you got the quotes from?

Comment: Can I keep this information anonymous? @Shaun I prefer to just say  that it can be found online. Is this allowed?

Comment: I suppose so :)